# If cell A contains "text1", type "text2 in cell B issue

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH to find a product name and type the SKU number to the cell next to it. Here's part of my code:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("iPhone Case - Black / iPhone 7";B3));"LK7B";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("iPhone Case - Black / iPhone 7 Plus";B3));"LK7PB"))
```

It works but the problem is the if the product is the iPhone 7 Plus, it still returns the SKU for the iPhone 7 as the product text is the exact same up until the "Plus" part.

How could I solve this problem so it returns the SKU for the plus model?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just reverse the order of the searches, in general any text that might contain another text should come first